# Command$ value disappears

Tags: vb6, command-line-arguments

I have a VB6 app.  I am trying to figure out what command line parameters got passed into the application.  If I type in `? Command$` into the Immediate window, it prints out the command line params fine.  Same, if I place `Command$` into the Watch window.

However, if I assign the Command$ function to a string:

```
Dim s as string 
s = Command$
```

the `s` variable will be empty.

What am I missing here?
I should mention that the code in question is located not in the main form, but in a DLL 2 levels down (e.g. the form calls DLL1, then DLL1 calls DLL2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the `GetCommandLine()` API would be an alternative (it should work for anything thats in-process with the executable) so you could try that instead of `Command$`.